# PHP Mailer envia email 2 vezes

Tags: php

Estive procurando por esse problema aqui no fórum, mas não o encontrei. Se existir um link e alguém puder me mandar fico grato. O problema é o seguinte:

Esse meu formulário, envia 2 emails para o destinatário que eu configuro. Olhei repetidas vezes o código, mas não entendi o porque disso.

PHP

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$texto = $_POST['texto'];
$enviar= $_POST['enviar'];
if(isset($enviar)){
$corpoMSG = "Oi, meu nome é: ".$nome."<br /><br />".$texto;
$assunto = "Teste para envio de email";
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
 $mail   = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->SetFrom('email@email.com.br', 'Orçamento');
 $address = "diegosouzasilva91@gmail.com";
 $mail->AddAddress($address, "destinatario");
 $mail->Subject = $assunto;
 $mail->MsgHTML($corpoMSG);
 if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><p style='padding: 0; margin: 0;'>Email não enviado.</p></div>"; 
  } else {
echo "<div class='alert alert-success'><p style='padding: 0; margin: 0;'>
Email enviado com sucesso!</p></div>";  }}
```

Comment: esta fazendo duas requisições ?

Comment: como verifico isso?

Comment: vai no seu navegador, botão direito, inspecionar elemento e console.

Comment: Esse é todo o código do arquivo? não parece ter nenhum problema, verifique se não existem nenhum `cc` perdido ou de um `echo` em todos os endereços(`to`,`cc` e `cco`)

Comment: É sim. o html é apenas um form com dois inputs de texto e o botão de enviar.

Comment: Gabriel, aqui no console não aparece nada. No caso eu sempre o uso para o js. Como faço para usá-lo para o php?

Comment: Aperta F12 no Chrome, vai na guia "Network", lá mostra todas as páginas que são acessadas. Veja se essa página que envia não é chamada 2 vezes.

Comment: hum... bem interessante... Nessa guia apareceu 2 vezes a página que envia o formulário. Uma com o método post (o que estou usando no formulário) e do tipo "document". A outra usa o método get e o tipo "text/html"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumindo que o código php está no mesmo arquivo do formulário:

Este erro ocorre porque não está sendo feita uma verificação se o formulário foi postado ou não (se o usuário clicou no submit ou não). Dessa forma toda vez que a página carrega o e-mail é enviado e quando o formulário é postado o formulário é enviado outra vez.

Você pode corrigir seu código colcando um if para verificar se o request é um post:

```
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
$texto = $_POST['texto'];

$enviar= $_POST['enviar'];
if(isset($enviar)){
$corpoMSG = "Oi, meu nome é: ".$nome."<br /><br />".$texto;
$assunto = "Teste para envio de email";
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
 $mail   = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->SetFrom('email@email.com.br', 'Orçamento');
 $address = "diegosouzasilva91@gmail.com";
 $mail->AddAddress($address, "destinatario");
 $mail->Subject = $assunto;
 $mail->MsgHTML($corpoMSG);
 if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><p style='padding: 0; margin: 0;'>Email não enviado.</p></div>"; 
  } else {
echo "<div class='alert alert-success'><p style='padding: 0; margin: 0;'>
Email enviado com sucesso!</p></div>";  }}
}
```

Comment: Tentei fazer o que pediu Rafael, mas não adiantou. Usei esse mesmo form que envia o email para fazer um cadastro no banco de dados, e quando fui conferir os registros lá, ele gravou 2 vezes o mesmo registro. Parece que ele tá enviando a página 2 vezes.

Comment: Pelo seu histórico no network do chrome, é isso que está acontecendo. Dà pra tentar uma gambiarra: dentro dos parenteses do if, troca tudo por isset($_POST['nome'])    dessa forma a parte do e-mail só vai rodar se o campo nome estiver preenchido. Se não for isso, está faltando código e você vai ter que postar.

Comment: Eu fiz um teste aqui, colocando uma página no action do form. botei em um outro caminho e deu certinho! Teve um detalhe que não relatei aqui e não sei se teria muito interferência, ´e que estou usando o wordpress. o formulário se encontra numa página do wordpress e eu estava usando um plugin para fazer isso. Só mudei o action e coloquei para uma página php pura. E só registrou uma vez no banco e só mandou um email. Achei bem estranho, porque já fiz isso outras vezes, e somente nessa vez que deu problema.

Comment: @DiegoSouza faz toda diferença o código estar dentro do wordpress, como falei antes, se não funcionasse tinha código faltando.